# IOS to PHP, How to store TimeStamp from IOS and store into MYSQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c

I have a table that needs to store the time stamp. The time stamp is created client side the sent to PHP script and i need to know how i store this time stamp into MYSQL table.

Also what data type do i need to set in MYSQL, the field data type that needs to store this time stamp?

IOS code:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
    activityIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255 green:0.0f/255 blue:0.0f/255 alpha:0.9f];
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    // 3) Load picker in background
    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

        NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

        NSString *myRequestString = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"ThreadName=%@&ThreadDesc=%@&CatId=%d&UID=%d&TimeStamp=%f", textFieldThreadName.text, textFieldThreadDesc.text, rowCategory, self.userID, timeStamp];
        NSString *response = [self setupPhpCall:myRequestString :@"insertThread.php"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self insertedThread:response];
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        });

    });
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

        include "connect.php";


        $threadName = $_POST["ThreadName"];
        $threadDesc = $_POST["ThreadDesc"];
        $catId = $_POST["CatId"];
        $uid = $_POST["UID"];
        $date = $_POST["TimeStamp"];


        $qry = "INSERT INTO Thread(T_U_ID,T_C_ID,T_Name,T_Description,T_Flagged,T_Rated) VALUES('$uid','$catId','$threadName','$threadDesc',$date,0,0)";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);


        if($result){

            echo 'inserted';
            exit();
        }else{
            echo 'not inserted';
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>
```

Comment: you can use `int(11)` for datatype, and also this screams `sql injection` escape your data, or use prepared statements.

Comment: the code is wide open to sql injection

Comment: HI thanks for feedback, but my timestamp is something like 1238774584.58576 and if i store as int(11) the time stamp gets store as 1238774584, is that correct?